# WordPress: wordpress/wp-content/themes/abdelkhalek/css/bootstrap.main.css?ver=5.7.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I'm invoke the `bootstrap.main.js` using `wp_enqueue_style` in `functions.php`
but i show that in console and bootstrap.main.js exists and path correct.

```
(index):32 GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/abdelkhalek/css/bootstrap.main.css?ver=5.7.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):75 GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/abdelkhalek/js/bootstrap.main.js?ver=5.7.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):75 GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/abdelkhalek/js/bootstrap.main.js?ver=5.7.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed the version from the wp_enqueue_style script :

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' , array(), null);
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.css' , array(), null);
```

The last parameter `null` is the version, which leads to 404 Error if you set the version 5.7.1 there.

Answer (score 0):

your JavaScript  calling system is default true which is footer area if you set it false then it add on header area. so go through as below lines.

wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' , array(), null);
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.css' , array(), true);